# how to set the focus to a text field of an application employed in i-pad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, focus

how to set the focus to a text field of an application employed in i-pad after getting sending request to the server?

is it possible by using javascript?

(this thing is working in normal browsers like safari ,firefox, I.E etc.,)

i dont know how to do this possible in i-pad?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: my concern is about webapp....

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering the focus event in your touch event handler. That's the only I could get it to work. SetTimeout won't work for some reason.